# Cannot display dashicon on TinyMCE Editor Button

Tags: dashicons

I have created an TinyMCE Editor (in admin only) button which appears in editor toolbar fine and functioning properly. Right now the button says “Live Chat”, what I want to replace with a dashicon or a font awesome icon.

I have the following code in my plugin.js file:

```
ed.addButton('livechat', {
  text: 'Live Chat',
  icon: 'dashicons dashicons-admin-links',
  tooltip: 'Live Chat',
  cmd: 'livechatButtonCmd',
});
```

Instead of showing a dashicon, it is showing a small empty rectangle. What is the correct way of doing this?